# path of controller not found in ajax magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers

Problem statement:

- My controller's name is "Index"
- The action inside is "Index"
- My route id and front name  are "evals"

Question:
What do I put in the url in javascript to get the right path of my controller. I put this:

```
 type : "POST",
                    url : '/evals/index',
                    data: {'idRate':therate},
```

but as result i got an error: `POST http://localhost/sajjada/evals/index/evals/index 404 (Not Found)`

Can you please help me?

Comment: what is your base URL?

Comment: http://localhost/sajjada this is my base url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Url should be

```
http://localhost/sajjada/evals/index/index
```

Assume that  http://localhost/sajjada is your magento base url

**URL Format at magento2:**

> baseURL/frontenName/ControllerPath/ActionName

Comment: but when i put my website on server it will change !!

Comment: Onlky changes BASE URL  like `http://example.com/evals/index/index`